# Use path bar and address bar in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, files, customization

By default, Nautilus use/show the path bar:

[image: Nautilus path bar]

---

Using [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) I managed to set by default the address bar:

[image: Nautilus address bar]

---

Is it possible to set both of them as default (show both: the buttons *and* the text input)?

Note: I know that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to switch between them, so I'm not interested about this.

Comment: What do you mean? Show both the buttons *and* the text input?

Comment: @oli Exactly. But I think that the only way is to modify the source code of Nautilus. I tried before, but without success...

Comment: I still don't understand. Would you have both bars on screen one above the other?

Comment: Can you use Nemo instead of Nautilus?

Comment: +1 for the `Ctrl+L` shortcut

Comment: As moving from win10 to Ubuntu. Win has it as buttons, once you click on an empty area along the line of the buttons, the area will be automatically converted to a text field.

Comment: This is one of my favorite things about the Windows Explorer. I use it almost every day.

Comment: This solution makes it permanently: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154115/161428

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do so.

The reasoning of "is it really not possible to do so" might be uninteresting, but I can say something about why it isn't, and probably shouldn't be, possible.

Fair warning: the answer is wordy. Its lengthy, but I believe its sensible. While I highly recommend that you do read on, feel free to not read on.

- The design of nautilus: Having an option to display both would require disproportionate vertical widening of the icons area, as now there would be two lines required to display the pathbar as well as address bar. But then other buttons on the right would have slack space above and below them, unless they readjust themselves, which is again a big design question by itself.
- The aesthetics of nautilus: Having both pathbar and address bar would be awfully ugly to see.
- Most people, and I mean barring a handful of exceptions like you and me, people have preference for either. Its a clear choice for them. Having an option to "tweak" this would mean cluttering the preferences section of nautilus, again to no avail. In fact, in the recent version, you can see that a lot of configuration and menu options have been removed, or hidden to make the overall experience of the nautilus very very simple.
- Wastage of screen real-estate: You would require only either of them at any point. This is true even if you are a person who use both of them multiple times throughout the day. You would want just either of them at any time, and it just makes sense, even from your point of view, to actually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> when you want the access to the other thing. Seeing the unrequired alternative on the screen would clutter the thinking process too.

Comment: This is something Windows did right, by merging them together.

Comment: most of the answer is fluff anyways, so TL;DR, having both is impossible at the time of writing but you can switch to path bar using `Ctrl+L` and switch back to buttons using `Esc`.

Comment: Windows has it as buttons (clickable links) by default, however, once you click on an empty area along the bar line of the buttons, the area will be automatically converted to a text field and the user can copy/edit/paste the new path. Once the text field loses focus, it goes back to buttons.

Comment: This is Linux we should be able to control it. I have a 43 inch monitor I don't care if a few extra pixels are needed for this functionality, which would obviously be helpful. Sometimes function needs to override aesthetics. Plus, windows did it right just replicate what they did .

Comment: *uninstalls nautilus (thanks for the explanation though!)

Comment: I can use the search but something is not right if i can't add an absolute path into the search box.

Comment: its= of it. 
it's= it is.

It doesn't look ugly on mac or windows. One should expect more from a file browser of an OS that needs C skills to operate and it is supposed to have an audience which also requires to be responsible when using power and blah blah blah.

Comment: "Most people prefer either one or the other, so having an option would clutter preferences to no avail." That statement makes no sense whatsoever lol.

Comment: @bviktor Not to mention plenty of people, when given the option, switch back and forth. Buttons are better for quick navigation, awhile path is better when you are copy-pasting locations.

Comment: What a horrible, stupid idea, I'm happy i'm not using Gnome.

Comment: The fact that I had to search on the Internet to find out how to be able to navigate directly to a path in Nautilus, and that "Search for filename" doesn't actually accept a full path, is a terrible user experience.

Answer (score 64):

Whilst I don't know if at all possible in Nautilus, I beleive Thunar may serve your wishes. It shows the button bar by default, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will result in the text bar popping out as shown below, allowing you to copy/paste or change directory by typing. When you press enter it goes away and you have the button bar. You have the best of both worlds.

[image]

In my opinion Thunar is "quicker" than nautilus but have no figures to back this up. It has an incredibly simple look and interface which I prefer.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 this is actually works a lot better and is much closer to what OP wanted.

Comment: True solution, works on ubntu 18.04

Comment: Working on Manjaro Phavo. Finally! So happy with Thunar, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 40):

I don't think it's possible to have both buttons and path at the same time.

On a side note, another way to permanently enable the path instead of buttons is to use [dconf](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/), a "low-level key/value database designed for storing desktop environment settings".  Install `dconf-tools` and launch `dconf-editor`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --yes dconf-tools
$ dconf-editor
```

Then navigate to `org > gnome > nautilus > preferences` and check `always-use-location-entry`.

Comment: +10 for this answer! On my Ubuntu 19.04 package have different name, ie `sudo apt install dconf-editor`.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. The others are just fluff trying to sound intelligent without  solving the problem at hand!

Comment: Note that in 20.04 it appears that the package name is dconf-editor too. Also Ubuntu Mate users should set `org.mate.caja.preferences.always-use-location-entry`.

Comment: `dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/always-use-location-entry true` dconf is already present in (at least) Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 20):

First install `dconf-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

After installation open `dconf-editor` go to `org –> gnome –> nautilus –> preferences` and choose `always-use-location-entry`

[image: Added image that highlights the change]

Comment: This should work in Mate as well.  For Caja, the location is org/mate/caja/preferences and the `always-use-location-entry` option.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure whether you prefer only **nautilus**, but I am writing in a hope that you would like this. You have helped me many times hope I'll return the same at least once.

[XFE](http://roland65.free.fr/xfe/) can display the path bar and address bar in much better way. Here are some images:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]
[image: screenshot 4]

I found this file manager so useful and currently I'm sticking to it :)

To install in Ubuntu just execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfe
```

Comment: These images are no longer available.

Comment: Pretty decent and **fast** file explorer, however it's also pretty ugly and does not use system theme.

Answer (score 4):

There is a one-liner I have used a few times to switch from bread-crumb view to editable text address bar:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

For ubuntu Mate:

```
gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

I have used it on 18.x; 19.x and 20.04.

To switch the default back to bread-crumb view, simply re-run and replace "true" with "false"

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to install `nautilus-terminal`, which embed a terminal in the nautilus window, so you could enter the desired path with `cd`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-terminal
```

Comment: Why would people downvote without giving a comment as to why they are downvoting? This seems like a constructive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **gnome-commander** -- there you have what you are asking for, and a bunch of other things. Find it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/gnome-commander).

[image]